# Как установить новую версию ubuntu с уже запущенной?

Tags: ubuntu

Работа ведется по сети через удаленное подключение по Xrdp. Есть ли возможность переустановить ubuntu на новую версию, чтобы не пропало соединение по сети?
С уже запущенной?

Comment: Вам нужно установить вторую версию в параллель? Или проапгрейдить старую? Во втором случае все должно работать как и раньше.

Comment: не апгрейдить, а именно переустановить перезатерев всю. Так как после апгрейда она поломала всю разработку.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно будет обратиться к вашему поставщику услуг VPS/VDS

Comment: нет это мой рабочий компьютер. Я просто. не хочу в офис сейчас ехать и настраивать. Отсюда вопрос получится ли удаленно или это невозможно?

Comment: в теории это можно сделать. Я так генту ставил с под убунту - нужно все сделать в chroot и аккуратно настроить. Правда шансы все сломать ну очень большие.

Comment: А, вот и чуть подробностей относительно прошлого твоего вопроса. Прям детектив.